# Description list with aligned descriptions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumitem, description

[This forum thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7607) is exactly what I'm looking for. I want my description environment to produce this:

```
Label is long   text 
lab2            blalballalaa
label3          possible second rule
label four      hello world
```

Someone offered this:

```
\newenvironment{mydescription}[1]                                                
  {\begin{list}{}%
   {\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1:\hfill}%
   \settowidth\labelwidth{\makelabel{#1}}%
   \setlength\leftmargin{\labelwidth}
   \addtolength\leftmargin{\labelsep}}}
  {\end{list}}
```

Which works great (the parameter is the longest label), except I think the `enumitem` should be able to do this. Unfortunately, the documentation for it is extremely confusing to me. Could someone show me how to achieve the same result with `enumitem`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries The longest label}]
  \item[The longest label] text
  \item[Short]  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `leftmargin=!` option!

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but the same `description` is giving me the following error:  `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ^^I\item[The longest label]`

Comment: What does the `leftmargin=!` do?

Comment: @JakubArnold I have seen the same error and it went away after including the `enumitem` package like shown in the example. Copying the options alone isn't enough.

Comment: If you put `\hfill` before each item label (such as `\item[\hfill Short]`), then the labels will be right-aligned. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

A solution using the `scrextend` package (taken from [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures)):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\begin{labeling}{alligator}  % alligator is the longest label
    \item [\textbf{ant}]really busy all the time
    \item [chimp] likes bananas
    \item [alligator] very dangerous animal, sharp teeth, long
     muscular tail and a bit of text that is longer than one
     line and shows the alignment of text quite nicely
\end{labeling}
\end{document}
```

[image]