# description, enumitem, beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, enumitem, description

I am looking for a similar solution as here [Description list with aligned descriptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67720/description-list-with-aligned-descriptions) 
except that I want to use it with `beamer`. If I use `enumitem` with `beamer`, inner theme is replaced by `enumitem`. I do not want to use `enumitem` because of this problem. Is there any alternative package or solution which works only with `description`? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Try this: `\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{mydescription}[1]
  {\begin{list}{}%
   {\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\bfseries##1\hfill}%
   \settowidth\labelwidth{\makelabel{#1}}%
   \setlength\leftmargin{\labelwidth}
   \addtolength\leftmargin{\labelsep}}}
  {\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{mydescription}{The longest label}
  \item[The longest label] text
  \item[Short]  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
\end{mydescription}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possibility adaption the answer linked in the question to the `beamer` settings:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\def\Mdescription#1{%
  \advance\beamer@descdefault by \labelsep%
  \list
  {}
  {\labelwidth\beamer@descdefault%
  \leftmargin\beamer@descdefault%
  \let\makelabel\beamer@descriptionitem
  \settowidth\labelwidth{\beamer@descriptionitem{#1}}%
  \setlength\leftmargin{\labelwidth}% 
  \addtolength\leftmargin{\labelsep}%
  }%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\def\endMdescription{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\endlist}
\long\def\beamer@descriptionitem#1{%
  \def\insertdescriptionitem{#1}%
  {\usebeamertemplate**{description item}}\hfil}
\makeatother  

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame} 
\begin{Mdescription}{The longest label}
\item[The longest label] some text 
\item[Short] some additional text so we can see line wrapping in the example 
\end{Mdescription} 

\begin{Mdescription}{ABC} 
\item[A] some text 
\item[ABC] some additional text so we can see line wrapping in the example  
\end{Mdescription} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

There's only one caveat: the `Mdescription` environment doesn't use now an optional argument of the form `<+->`, so overlay specifications will have to be made in `\item`.