# How to make a space between the item at description?

Tags: xetex, lyx, lists, description, hebrew

Here is a MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}
\newfontfamily{\am}{Open Sans Hebrew}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\bfseries\am\textcolor{blue}{#1:}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [{כחגלדך}] דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום
דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט
לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג
סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו
ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see there text is below the blue word. Can I separate them?
i.e.:
All of the text will be after the black line. Can I do something like this?
[image]

In other words - it is possible to make a space for the labels (blue words) and space for the text that they wont mix?

EDIT:
I use this solution to design my  description  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7629070/2013542, so there is something that I can add for this that it will work?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can achieve the desired result with the `enumitem` package. You could then use something like `\begin{description}[labelwidth =<width of your choice>]`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67720/description-list-with-aligned-descriptions

Comment: Thank you @DavidPurton! But I'm using LyX so I need a solution for this (e.g. something to put at the preamble...)

Comment: If you want a quick solution, a `tabularx` environment would do the trick. Can `LyX` use `tabularx`?

Comment: Or how about this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130097/87678

Comment: I'm not sure I can use it with LyX...

Comment: But the is a way to do it via this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7629070/2013542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer slightly adjusts [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/87678) to a similar problem, so that you only need make changes in the preamble and can continue to use the `description` environment as normal in LyX.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}

%% variable width label description set up
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\newlength\widest
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace{\labelsep}%
  \bfseries\textcolor{blue}{#1:}}
\newlist{heblyxdesc}{description}{1}
\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{description}{%
  \vbox{%
    \global\setlength\widest{0pt}%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1:}}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\global\setlength\widest{\@tempdima}\fi%
    }%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}%
  }
  \begin{heblyxdesc}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest,
    style=unboxed]
  \BODY
  \end{heblyxdesc}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[כחגלדך] דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג
    סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום
  \item[כחגלדך כחגלדך]
    דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו
    ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו ביום דג סקרן שט
    לו ביום דג סקרן שט לו
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you!! It's Works! But if put a very long word this is what happen: https://i.imgur.com/NqqZ39r.png (look at the third label). How can I fix this?

Comment: @heblyx, I can not reproduce this with my MWE. Even long labels work properly. Check carefully that there are no differences from my code. And if still, then you could ask another question with a MWE.