# enumitem - understanding horizontal spacing

Tags: enumitem

I am baffling with horizontal spacing for description list given by [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem#:%7E:text=CTAN%3A%20Package%20enumitem%20enumitem%20%E2%80%93%20Control%20layout%20of,three%20basic%20list%20environments%3A%20enumerate%2C%20itemize%20and%20description.) package. I would like to have dots lined up under each other. I expect that `\labelident` is the right parameter, but I am confused. My MWE is below:

```
  \begin{description}[labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=3cm, style=standard]
    \item[\(V_\text{m}\)]       \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 1},
    \item[\(ω t + \varphi_0\)]  \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 2},
    \item[\(ω\)]                \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 3},
    \item[\(t\)]                \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 4}.
  \end{description}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like what is mentioned here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67720/description-list-with-aligned-descriptions

Comment: Are you sure that a simple `itemize` is not enough for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always provide MWE, which we can test as it is

I would consider  @Sigur comment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
some text
 \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=5em]
    \item[\(V_{\mathrm{m}}\)]           \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 1},
    \item[\(\omega t + \varphi_0\)] \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 2},
    \item[\(\omega\)]               \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 3},
    \item[\(t\)]                    \(\ldots\;\)\emph{text 4}.
  \end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want to set a suitable `labelwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{description}[
  labelwidth=4em,
  labelindent=\parindent,
  leftmargin=3cm,
  style=standard,
]
  \item[\(V_{\mathrm{m}}\)]   \dots\ \emph{text 1},
  \item[\(ω t + \varphi_0\)]  \dots\ \emph{text 2},
  \item[\(ω\)]                \dots\ \emph{text 3},
  \item[\(t\)]                \dots\ \emph{text 4}.
\end{description}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `V_\text{m}` is wrong under two respects:

1. outer braces ***are needed***, even if the output seems right;
2. `\text` should be `\mathrm`, because the former doesn't ensure upright font.

Also I'd not abuse math mode for the dots.